# Python - iterating through list and dictionary to get a nested list output

Tags: python, list, loops, dictionary, for-loop

I have a dictionary `mydict` which contains some filenames as keys and text within them as values.

I am extracting a list of words from the text in each file. Words are stored in a list `mywords`.

I have tried the following.

```py
mydict = {'File1': 'some text. \n Foo extract this. \n Bar extract this', 
'File2': 'more text. \n Bar extract this too.'}
mywords = ['Foo', 'Bar']
mylist= []
for k,v in mydict.items():
        for word in mywords:
            extracted = (re.findall('^ ' + word + ".*", v, flags=re.IGNORECASE|re.MULTILINE))
            mylist.append(extracted[:1])
```

This gives me

```py
[[' Foo extract this. '],
 [' Bar extract this'],
 [],
 [' Bar extract this too.']]
```

However, I want the output to have 2 nested lists (for each file) instead of a separate list each time it searches a word in a file.

Desired output:

```py
[[' Foo extract this. '], [' Bar extract this']],
 [[], [' Bar extract this too.']]
```

Comment: Why do you need lists with only 1 item in each?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to try making sublists and appending them to your list instead. Here's a possible solution:

```
mydict = {'File1': 'some text. \n Foo extract this. \n Bar extract this', 
'File2': 'more text. \n Bar extract this too.'}
mywords = ['Foo', 'Bar']
mylist= []
for k,v in mydict.items():
    sublist = []
    for word in mywords:
        extracted = (re.findall('^ ' + word + ".*", v, flags=re.IGNORECASE|re.MULTILINE))
        sublist.append(extracted[:1])
    mylist.append(sublist)
```

This outputs: `[[[' Foo extract this. '], [' Bar extract this']], [[], [' Bar extract this too.']]]`

---

If you wanted to have the strings without the surrounding list, insert the first result only if there is a result:

```
import re

mydict = {'File1': 'some text. \n Foo extract this. \n Bar extract this', 
'File2': 'more text. \n Bar extract this too.'}
mywords = ['Foo', 'Bar']
mylist= []
for k,v in mydict.items():
    sublist = []
    for word in mywords:
        extracted = (re.findall('^ ' + word + ".*", v, flags=re.IGNORECASE|re.MULTILINE))
        if extracted: # Checks if there is at least one element in the list
            sublist.append(extracted[0])
    mylist.append(sublist)
```

This outputs: `[[' Foo extract this. ', ' Bar extract this'], [' Bar extract this too.']]`

---

If you want to be able to get several results from each file, you can do as follows (note that I put another match for `Foo` in the second file:

```
import re

mydict = {'File1': 'some text. \n Foo extract this. \n Bar extract this', 
'File2': 'more text. \n Bar extract this too. \n Bar extract this one as well'}
mywords = ['Foo', 'Bar']
mylist= []
for k,v in mydict.items():
    sublist = []
    for word in mywords:
        extracted = (re.findall('^ ' + word + ".*", v, flags=re.IGNORECASE|re.MULTILINE))
        if extracted:
            sublist += extracted
    mylist.append(sublist)
```

This outputs: `[[' Foo extract this. ', ' Bar extract this'], [' Bar extract this too. ', ' Bar extract
 this one as well']]`

Comment: is there a way to change all the `['values']` to `'values'`?